# Changing class to element doesn't change background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/abhinavthinktank/full/RgmBjZ/)! for the problem if someone wants to take a look, i'll post the relevant code here

The displayMoves() function shown here simulates moves in a simon game, it adds .colorRedBright class to an element to illuminate it, then removes same class after 250ms. However, As the game progresses i've noticed a bug where the div blinks only the last time **(ONLY IN RED COLOR)**. I've noticed that the class overrides the background-color property **(.redColorHover)** but the other divs work fine with this,I can't figure out this issue after some debugging.

```
function displayMoves() {
  var currentCircle = {},
    currentAudio, renderCircle;
  var colorBright, colorDark;
  currentCircle = circles[currentMoves[displayIndex]];
  currentAudio = document.getElementById(currentCircle["colorAndSound"][2]);
  colorBright = currentCircle["colorAndSound"][1];
  colorDark = currentCircle["colorAndSound"][0];
  renderCircle = document.getElementById(currentCircle.id);
  renderCircle.classList.add(colorBright);
  setTimeout(function() {
    renderCircle.classList.remove(colorBright);
  }, 250);
  currentAudio.play();
  displayIndex++;
  if (displayIndex == currentMoves.length) {
    clearInterval(displayMovesInterval);
    $(".header").text("Level " + currentMoves.length);
    unlockGame();
  }
}
```

Comment: jQuery only for changing the text? O.o

Comment: @Andreas Keep in mind you're looking at only one function out of 230 lines. If you take a look at the codepen, jQuery is being used quite a bit for things like animations etc.

Comment: What ^ @Santi said, Also im learning , my code may not be properly structured..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the order of your CSS. You add `.colorBrightRed` and `.colorRedNoHov` to the element when it flashes, and for the red colors, `.colorRedNoHov` comes after `.colorBrightRed` so it's overwriting the style. Just move `.colorRedNoHov` before `.colorBrightRed` so that `.colorBrightRed`  will override `.colorRedNoHov` when both classes are applied to the element.

https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/mwYQgx

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 //Monochromatic yellow BRIGHT ->#ffff33
 //Monochromatic green  BRIGHT ->#00ff00
 //Monochromatic red BRIGHT    ->#ff0000
 //Monochromatic blue BRIGHT   ->#0000ff

 /* https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3,
    https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3,
    https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3,
    https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3.
*/
 var currentMoves;
 var playButton;
 var isStrict;
 var circles;
 var colorsAndSounds;
 var displayMovesInterval;
 var displayIndex;
 var allCircles;
 var currentIndex;
 var noHoverClasses;

 /*Used for error audio
 The AudioContext interface represents an audio-processing graph built from audio modules linked together,
 each represented by an AudioNode. An audio context controls both the creation of the nodes
    it contains and the execution of the audio processing, or decoding.
 You need to create an AudioContext before you do anything else, as everything happens inside a context.*/
 var audioCtx;
 var errorOscill;
 var ramp;
 var vol;
 var errNode;
 init();
 
});


function init() {
 
 playButton = document.getElementById("playButton");
 isStrict = false;
 noHoverClasses = ["colorYellowNoHov","colorGreenNoHov","colorRedNoHov","colorBlueNoHov"];

 colorsAndSounds = {
  "yellow":["colorYellow","colorBrightYellow","audio1"],
  "green":["colorGreen","colorBrightGreen","audio2"],
  "red":["colorRed","colorBrightRed","audio3"],
  "blue":["colorBlue","colorBrightBlue","audio4"]
 };
 playButton.onclick = initialiseGame;
    initialiseErrorSound();
}

function initialiseErrorSound() {
 audioCtx = new AudioContext();
 errorOscill =  audioCtx.createOscillator();
 ramp = 0.05;
 vol = 0.5;
 errorOscill.type = "triangle";
 errorOscill.frequency.value = "110";
    errorOscill.start(0.0); //delay optional parameter is mandatory on Safari
    errNode = audioCtx.createGain();
    errorOscill.connect(errNode);
    errNode.gain.value = 0;
    errNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
}


function playError() {
  errNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(vol, audioCtx.currentTime + ramp);
}

function stopError() {
  errNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, audioCtx.currentTime + ramp);
}
 

function initialiseGame() {
currentMoves = [];
currentIndex = 0;
circles = [];
isStrict = document.getElementById("strict").checked;
//Set initial colors and sounds for various circles, 
//Bind their ids in the DOM.
var cnsKeys = Object.keys(colorsAndSounds);
for(var i =1;i<=4;i++)
{
 var newCircle = {};
 newCircle["id"] = "circle"+i;
 newCircle["colorAndSound"] = colorsAndSounds[cnsKeys[i-1]];
 circles.push(newCircle);
 
}

changeDisplay();
startGame();

}

function changeDisplay() {
 playButton.className = "fa fa-refresh hoverBlue fa-2x";
 $(".header").animate({left: '-=5200px'});
  setTimeout(function() {
     $(".header").text("Level "+currentMoves.length);
   },500);
 $(".header").css("font-size",'2.5em');
 $(".header").animate({left: '+=5200px'});
 $("#strictAndNotif ").hide();
  
}


function startGame() {
addMove();
playGame();
}


function addMove() {

var randomMove = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
currentMoves.push(randomMove);


}

function playGame () {
 //Initialise value of displayIndex for changing css and playing sound.
 lockGame();
 displayIndex = 0; ""
 displayMovesInterval = setInterval(displayMoves ,1000);
}


function displayMoves() {
 var currentCircle = {}, currentAudio, renderCircle;
 var colorBright , colorDark;
 currentCircle = circles[currentMoves[displayIndex]];
 currentAudio = document.getElementById(currentCircle["colorAndSound"][2]);
 colorBright =  currentCircle["colorAndSound"][1];
 colorDark = currentCircle["colorAndSound"][0];
 renderCircle = document.getElementById(currentCircle.id);
 renderCircle.classList.add(colorBright);
 setTimeout(function() {
   renderCircle.classList.remove(colorBright);
 },250);
 currentAudio.play();
 displayIndex++;
 if(displayIndex==currentMoves.length)
 {
 clearInterval(displayMovesInterval);
 $(".header").text("Level "+currentMoves.length);
 unlockGame();
 }
}

function lockGame() {
 var i= 0;
 allCircles = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");
    allCircles.forEach(function(circle) {
     circle.onclick = "";
     circle.classList.remove(circles[i]["colorAndSound"][0]);
     circle.classList.add(noHoverClasses[i]);
     i++;
    })
    
}

function unlockGame() {
 var i =0;
    allCircles = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");
    allCircles.forEach(function(circle) {
     circle.onclick = moveClicked;
     circle.classList.remove(noHoverClasses[i]);
     circle.classList.add(circles[i]["colorAndSound"][0]);
     circle.classList.remove(noHoverClasses[i]);
     i++;
    })
}


function moveClicked() {
 var divClicked = this.id;
 var circleDiv = circles[currentMoves[currentIndex]];
 var supposedToClick =  circleDiv.id;
 var soundToPlay;
 if(supposedToClick == divClicked)
 {
 console.log("Great success!");
 soundToPlay = document.getElementById(circleDiv["colorAndSound"][2]);
 soundToPlay.play();
 currentIndex++;
 if(currentIndex==currentMoves.length)
 {
  //20th level win condition
  if(currentIndex == 20)
  {
  setTimeout(initialiseGame,5000);
  $(".header").text("You win! Reset in 5 seconds! ");
  shake();
  }
  else {
  addMove();
  currentIndex = 0;
  playGame();
  }
 }
 }
 else
 {
  
  shake();
  currentIndex = 0;
  playError();
  setTimeout(stopError,250);
  if(isStrict)
  setTimeout(initialiseGame,1100);
  else
  playGame();
 }
 
}

function shake () {
 $(".header").animate({left: '-=50px'},250);
 $(".header").animate({left: '+=50px'},250);
 $(".header").animate({left: '-=50px'},250);
 $(".header").animate({left: '+=50px'},250);
}
```

```css
body{
 font-family: 'Rajdhani',sans-serif;
 background-color:black;
 color:white;
} 

.circle {
 position:relative;
 height:10vw;
 width:10vw;
 border-radius:50%;
}


#content {
 position:absolute;
 display:inline-block;
 left:40vw;
 width:20vw;
 margin-top:1%;
}

/* YELLOW*/
.colorYellow {
 background-color: #e5e500;
}

.colorYellowNoHov {
 background-color:#e5e500;
}

.colorBrightYellow {
 background-color: #ffff33;
}

#circle1 {
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
}

/* BRIGHT YELLOW */
.colorYellow:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
 background-color:#ffff33;
}



/*GREEN */

.colorGreen {
 background-color: #00b300;
}

#circle2 {
 top:0%;
 left:10vw;
}

.colorGreenNoHov {
 background-color:#00b300;
}

 /*green  BRIGHT ->#00ff00*/

.colorGreen:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
 background-color:#00ff00;
}

.colorBrightGreen {
 background-color:#00ff00 
}

/*RED Color */
#circle3 {
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
}

.colorRed {
 background-color:#b20000;
}

.colorRedNoHov {
 background-color:#b20000;
}

.colorBrightRed {
 background-color:#ff0000;
}

/* red BRIGHT    ->#ff0000*/
.colorRed:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
 background-color:#ff0000;
}



/*BLUE Color */
#circle4 {
 bottom:0;
 left:10vw;
}

.colorBlue {
 background-color:#000099;
}

.colorBlueNoHov {
 background-color:#000099;
}

.colorBrightBlue {
 background-color:#0000ff;
}

/* blue BRIGHT   ->#0000ff */
.colorBlue:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
 background-color:#0000ff;
}

.signature {
 position:relative;
}

.header {
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:5em;
 height:150px;
 right:0;
 margin:0 auto;
}

.startButton {
 border-radius:10%;
 font-size:2.5em;
 padding:1%;
 justify-content: center;
 display:inline-block;
}

.startButtonContainer {
 text-align:center;
}


.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: red;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px red;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#strictAndNotif {
 font-size:1.2em;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:100px;
 margin-top:1%;
 color:red;
 transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.fa-play-circle {
 font-size:2em;
 color:white;
}

.hoverBlue {
 color:black;

}

.hoverBlue:hover {
 color:blue;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.fa-play-circle:hover {
 color:blue;
 cursor:pointer;

}

.fa-play-circle:focus {
 font-size:1em;
 color:blue;
 cursor:pointer;

}

a {
 text-decoration:none;
}

a {
 font-size:1.2em;
 color:white;
 text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover {
 color:blue;
}

a:visited {
 color:#87CEFA;
}

a:visited:hover {
 color:blue;
}

.header-container {
 height:150px;
 width:100%;
}

.fa-heart {
 color:red;
 font-size:1.2em;
}

.fa-refresh {
 color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rajdhani" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="simon.css">
<script src="simon.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class ="header-container">
<div class="header">SIMON</div>
<audio id="audio1"  preload="auto" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="audio2" preload="auto" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="audio3" preload="auto" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="audio4" preload="auto" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3"></audio>
</div>
<div class="startButtonContainer"><div class="startButton"><i id="playButton" class="fa fa-play-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></div>
<div id ="strictAndNotif">
<label class="switch"><input id="strict" type="checkbox">
<span class="slider round"></span>
STRICT
</label></div>
<div id = "content">
<div id = "circle1" class ="circle colorYellow"></div>
<div id = "circle2" class ="circle colorGreen"></div>
<div id = "circle3" class ="circle colorRed"></div>
<div id = "circle4" class ="circle colorBlue"></div>
<div class="signature">
<p style="text-align:center"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
<p style="text-align:center"><a href="https://github.com/abhinav-thinktank">Abhinav Mishra</a></p>
<p style="text-align:center"><a href="https://github.com/abhinav-thinktank">अभिनव मिश्रा</a></p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @abhinavm93 you're welcome :) fun game!! btw, throw `debugger;` in there after you apply classes that should work, and that will stop everything and allow you to inspect the document and see what's up.

Comment: I did debug it for some time, I knew the issue was with the classes, I thought i checked the classes ordering, but i definitely hadn't , thank you for the quick response :)